# i want to make slide menu with 3D effect like the below image

Tags: android, animation, user-interface, navigation-drawer

[image]

I am able to make the slider by using this code. But I dont know how to  make it in 3D.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.navdrawer.SimpleSideDrawer;

public class MainScreen extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new    PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
}
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements
    OnClickListener {
private ImageButton _Menu;
private SimpleSideDrawer slide_me;

public PlaceholderFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_screen,
            container, false);
    slide_me = new SimpleSideDrawer(getActivity());
    slide_me.setLeftBehindContentView(R.layout.slider_menu_inflator);

    _Menu = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.menu);
    _Menu.setOnClickListener(this);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.menu:
        slide_me.toggleLeftDrawer();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, Were you ever able to achieve it or did you just use AndroidResideMenu

Comment: Yes, check the accepted answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [AndroidResideMenu](https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu) Library for make slide menu with 3D effect

Comment: I did it. In ResideMenu.buildScaleDownAnimation change scaleDown.playTogether(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "scaleX", targetScaleX), ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "scaleY", targetScaleY)); add ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "rotationY", -20) and in ResideMenu.buildScaleUpAnimation change scaleUp.playTogether(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "scaleX", targetScaleX), ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "scaleY", targetScaleY)); add ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "rotationY", 0)

Comment: @Nevaeh go to Library project and open residemenu_item.xml add a linear layout under the textview with height 2 dp. By this you can create a divider

Comment: please give me the residemenu_item.xml full file

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25887088/how-to-add-divider-to-items-in-androidresidemenu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61404/discussion-between-renjith-krishnan-and-nevaeh).

Answer (score 1):

To give it a 3D translation effect, you need to put a camera in front of the view and then translate the camera and also change the angle with it. Check the code below for similar kind of effect to imageview. You can pick that part of the code and modify as per your need:

https://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/

Comment: dude its a slider menu like facebook when we tap on that menu button in custom title bar then menu will open like the image i had post and activity will move to the right side with 3d animation.well the coverflow is totally diffrent with this flow. @Sushil

Comment: @Pankaj.. I know you are talking about slider menu like in FB. Dont focus on Coverflow design. Just focus on the code which gives its 3D translation. Its by moving the camera sideways and away from a view. Try adding this kind of animation to your slider menu code.

Comment: i got the logic dude.thnx